# Fill field value automatically

Tags: entities

So let's say I have a content type Product with two fields: name and date. I want to have another field called profit to be filled in automatically according to the name of the product.
Any ideas on how I can do that easily?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to give to the [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module a try. It seems that it does exactly what you need.

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

Comment: I'm thinking Computed Field won't do the trick if he wants "on the fly" field updates.  See http://drupal.org/node/390172
A snippet of javascipt should do the job

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript solution for this.  For instance:

```
(function ($) {
  $("#edit-field-name-und-0-value").change(function(){
      $("#edit-field-profit-und-0-value").val(this.value);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When the user updates the Name field it will also update the Profit field.